# Android finding source image files on the android device inside the app assets or resources

Tags: android, android-studio

So, I am trying to place an image in a layout programmatically and I can do this, but only using the mipmap resources. I want to place the full image onto the layout. The answers I have come across mention bitmaps and file paths. What I am confused about is the file path part. Does this mean a file path on the computers source files, or does it mean a file path on the android device in which case, how can I find the image when it is part of the apps resources, not in gallery or to be taken from the camera. If i create a new directory in the project, I can't use R.XXX to find it as it is not there. Under Android the directory does not show up either and dragging an image to the directories under Android does nothing either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put images in res/drawable folder

Comment: When I do that they just show up as a small grey box

Comment: You can set size by yourself

Comment: But do I do it with image asset as a notification icon or action bar or tab notification?

Comment: I don't get you, this is not asset, but drawable. Do you want to use it as icon or just image?

Comment: Just as an image

Comment: Then just place your image in res/drawable or res/drawable-nodpi folder and you will be able to access it in layout by @drawable/image_name